# Update variable every time I run the function

Tags: c++

As the title says, I want to update a specific variable of a function and use it as input of the same function.
Trying to explain better:

```
double pi_control(double x, double integral_x, double dt) {
    integral_x = (x * dt) + integral_x;
    return integral_x;
}
```

x and dt are given variable (x = 3.0, dt = 0.01). integral_x (whose initial value is 0.0) after running pi_control is 0.03.
I want to run pi_control one more time, how can I override integral_x initial value and use 0.03 instead?

EDIT:

Full pi_control function

```
double pi_control(double x, double &integral_x, double kp, double ki, double dt) {
    integral_x = (x * dt) + integral_x;
    double u = - kp * x - ki * integral_x;
    return u;

}
```

Comment: Obviously this function was reported in that way only as an example. Thanks anyway

Comment: What do you mean override the value? It's already a parameter that you pass in. You can just pass in the updated value? You probably need to clarify your question.

Comment: Probably I haven't explained well. I have "integral_x" as input (with initial value 0.0). Integral_x, given x and dt as said before, after running one time the function became 0.03. I would like to use the new integral_x as input (instead the 0.0 initial value).

Comment: Would `integral_x = pi_control(x, integral_x, dt);` call work for you? If not, why? I think it's much more readable than passing `integral_x` by reference.

Comment: In reality my function it's a bit more complex. Integral_x is a parameter I have to use in pi_control to give another variable as output.  Everytime I run pi_control integral_x (input of pi_control) should have been updated. I edited the first post.

Comment: @sungfive Now, I don't understand your question. Your updated `pi_control` should do exactly what you was asking for. What is the problem with it?

Comment: pi_control gives me the controller (u) I have to use in a simple SISO model. Integral_x, given e.g. x=3.0 and dt=0.01 should be 0.00 at the beginning, 0.03 after one run, 0.06 after two, 0.09 after 3, etc... The updated integral_x has to be used every time I use pi_control function (integral_x input should be 0.00, then 0.03,...)

Answer (score 5):

Change the signature to take `integral_x` by reference:

```
double pi_control(double x, double &integral_x, double dt) { ... }
```

Now any changes made to the `integral_x` variable inside the function are reflected in the variable you pass in.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just return the new value of `integral_x` (note that as shown your function is declared to return a `double` but has no `return` statement -- that's undefined behaviour).

```
double pi_control (double x, double integral_x, double dt)
{
    integral_x = (x * dt) + integral_x;
    return integral_x;
}
```

Comment: I would prefer this solution as well since then the caller may decide whether to update its variable or not. Moreover, mixing pass-by-value and pass-by-reference is kind of ugly and can hinder reading/understanding of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer simply

```
integral_x = pi_control(x, integral_x, dt);
```

with

```
double pi_control(double x, double integral_x, double dt)
{
  return x * dt + integral_x;
}
```

There is no confusing mixing of pass-by-value and pass-by-reference parameters, and a caller can additionally decide whether they want to update `integral_x` or not.

I guess the performance would be the same, especially when the function can be inlined (a compiler can see it's definition during translation).

**UPDATE**

You changed the question considerably, but anyway, this solution is still possible:

```
std::pair<double, double> pi_control(double x, double integral_x, double kp, double ki, double dt)
{
  integral_x = (x * dt) + integral_x;
  double u = - kp * x - ki * integral_x;
  return {u, integral_x};
}
```

with

```
std::tie(u, integral_x) = pi_control(x, integral_x, kp, ki, dt);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to have the same result using pass-by-reference?